# sesu : not found no such file or directory in Jenkins ssh plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Trying to connect to the server using Jenkins ssh plugin and executing some commands. It's connected but sesu command is not working. Jenkins is unable to recognize sesu command. It says sesu : not found no such file or directory. When trying with putty, sesu command is working. Jenkins version is 2.7. Please help me on same. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can't enter password on Jenkins at run-time. Other option for accessing server is generate ssh-key. Use that key to access server from Jenkins.

Use putty or similar tools to create key.
Firstly, log in to your server using credentials.
Then switch to user who has all access rights by using sesu or other switch user command like sudo su. 
Execute below steps after that : 
**ssh-keygen -t rsa** 
hit enter for all steps without entering input.
then,
Once key is created, type **cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys** hit [Enter]

use created rsa private key after all these step in SSH plug and you are able to access unix server from Jenkins and execute commands on that server.

Answer (score 0):

Use **locate sesu** command. It will show path of sesu command. Use that one in spite of only sesu. e.g. /opt/CA/AccessControl/bin/sesu